# Linq Querying XML with nonstandard namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to Query an XML file however some node have name spaces others do not resulting in never getting the complete solution.

I was wondering if it was possible to do this without Xpath?

XML

```
<Household name="Home" xmlns="AP:CB" description="Home" >
    <InsuranceClaims/>
    <mortgages>
        <mortgage id="Sally Mae"  xmlns="AP:CB" />
    </mortgages>
    <Appliances>
        <Appliance key="Stove" value="5000"  />
    </Appliances>
    <Persons>
        <Person name="Henry" age="35" />
        <Person name="Jill" age="23" xmlns="AP:CB"/>
    </Persons>
</Household>
```

so we have a namespace of AP:CB that exists on some elements and not others.

My current attempts haven't produced any result.

```
_Household = _XDoc.Descendants()
                  .Where(x => x.Name == "Persons")
                  .Select(x => new
                         {
                             name = (string)x.Element( "Person").Attribute("name").Value,
                             age = (string)x.Element("Person").Attribute("age").Value
                         })
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.age, x => x.name);
```

I hope I have the general idea right.

edit: updated captialization to match case sensitivity, same result.
 Adding Value and changing the where clause to be in the descendant bracket did not work.

Comment: This is case sensitive, so name = (string)x.Element( "person") should be name = (string)x.Element( "Person").  Same for the age.  Not sure if that's the only problem, but it's surely a part of the problem.

Comment: What is your requirement? Why are you not commenting on posts if it don't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem with your code, as you correctly identified, is with XML namespaces. Though you're wrong that some elements in your code have them and some don't: a child node inherits the `xmlns` declaration from its parent, which means that all elements in the document are in the same namespace.

When using LINQ to XML on documents with namespaces, you have to specify that namespace explicitly:

```
XNamespace ns = "AP:CB";

…

_Household = _XDoc.Descendants()
                  .Where(x => x.Name == ns + "Persons")
                  .Select(x => new
                         {
                             name = (string)x.Element(ns + "Person").Attribute("name").Value,
                             age = (string)x.Element(ns + "Person").Attribute("age").Value
                         })
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.age, x => x.name);
```

Though this code will return only a single value (for Henry), because you select all `Persons` elements, and for each of them select its first `Person` child node.

Instead, I would write the query like this:

```
_Household = _XDoc.Descendants(ns + "Persons")
                  .Elements(ns + "Person")
                  .ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("age"), x => (string)x.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: I have learnt something new from your post. Thanks for the great post.

Comment: Thank you it worked greatly. Looks like I have to brush up on my XML.